# Git Pull stops Drush from working on my live server

Tags: git, drush

After running:

```
git pull origin master
```

on my live server (via SSH in Terminal) it causes some issues with my Drupal site.
But it also stops drush working on my live server.
For example, prior to latest git pull, I could run commands like this:

```
vendor/bin/drush cr
```

or this:

```
vendor/bin/drush updatedb
```

and they would work.
But after git pull, they no longer do anything and the Terminal acts as if they haven't been ran.
Is there any obvious reason for this that I could start looking for in order to fix drush?

Comment: No need to infer that the pull action itself caused problems. But the consequences can be anything, since you're modifying the repo on the server, so yes it can impact anything related to what's inside the repo. Applications, resources, etc. Hard to say more without knowing what's versioned here exactly.

Comment: Is there anything in logs and what is the diff output of the pull cmd ?